# How do you bind a ContentTemplate directly to a Grid?

Tags: wpf, contentpresenter

In the following XAML, I am trying to bind the various DataTemplates directly to the Grid ContentPresenter. I have put the Button inside the Grid just to prove to myself that the ContentTemplate is binding and the DataTriggers are working correctly - which they are (note I don't want any type of control at this point).
If I replace `<Button`> with `<ContentPresenter`> nothing shows up.
Obviously I'm missing something really simple here.

```
      <DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
        <Grid Style="{StaticResource GridAllocatedStyle}">
            <Ellipse Stroke="#FF5A71FB" 
                     StrokeThickness="0.5"
                     Style="{StaticResource EllipseFinanciallyAllocatedStyle}" />
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockInsideEllipseStyle}" 
                       Text="A"
                       ToolTip="Allocated" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>


    <DataTemplate x:Key="AllocationTemplate">
        <Grid>           
            <Button> <!-- I want to bind to the Grid.ContentPresenter here -->
                <Button.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Button">                             
                        <Style.Triggers>                               
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Allocated}" Value="PreAllocatedBoth">
                                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource MyTemplate}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Style>
            </Button>            
        </Grid>      
    </DataTemplate>
```

For completeness this is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="AllocationTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Grid">                    
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Allocated}" Value="None">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </DataTrigger>                       
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Grid.Style>
            <ContentPresenter> <!-- I want to bind to the Grid.ContentPresenter here -->
                <ContentPresenter.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">                             
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Allocated}" Value="FinanciallyAllocated">
                                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"  Value="{StaticResource MyTemplate}" />
                            </DataTrigger>                                                          
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ContentPresenter.Style>
            </ContentPresenter>            
        </Grid>      
    </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe nothing shows up because you do not have any content set in your `contentPresenter`?

p.s.: it looks like you have a lot of code which doesn't relate to the your issue (ellipse styles, many templates). It takes a while to go through all this code, so I'd ask to remove unneeded code.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is set the DataTemplate (MyTemplate) as the content of the content presenter - but obviously I need to provide a control that can accept the ContentTemplate. Which control would I use here, given that I want to display the content of MyTemplate?

Comment: @Jeremy, Well, this usage looks correct. `ContentPresenter` should accept `DataTemplate`. The only alternative to `ContentPresenter` is `ContentControl` but I doubt this change will help you.

Comment: unfortunately, that's exactly the problem - the DataTemplate doesn't show up. I'll have a go at ContentControl and see if that makes any difference. In any event, I refactored the whole thing, so that it no longer uses the DataTemplate - but it now looks horribly messy:) If I bind to the Button as in the first example,I get the correct binding, so I know that the DataTrigger is working, but as stated above, I just want the contents of the DataTemplate to appear inside the grid.